# How to query the Alfresco Audit Service in Java

Tags: java, alfresco, audit

I can easily query the [Alfresco audit](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/audit-intro.html) log [in REST](https://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/audit-rest-api.html) using this query:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/audit/query/audit-custom?verbose=true
```

But how to perform the same request in Java within Alfresco module?
It must be synchronous.

A lazy solution would be to call the REST URL in Java, but it would probably be inefficient, and more importantly it would require me to store an admin's password somewhere.

I noticed [AuditService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/audit/AuditService.html) has a [auditQuery](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/audit/AuditService.html#auditQuery-org.alfresco.service.cmr.audit.AuditService.AuditQueryCallback-org.alfresco.service.cmr.audit.AuditQueryParameters-int-) method so I am trying to call it. Unfortunately it seems to be for asynchronous operations? I don't need callbacks, as I need to wait until the queried data is ready before going on to the next step.

Comment: Read the source code of the webscript you're calling, and see how that does it? (Alfresco is handily open source so you can!)

Comment: @Gagravarr: Done, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation, mostly copied from [the source code of the REST API](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/remote-api/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/web/scripts/audit/AuditQueryGet.java#L113):

```
int maxResults = 10000;
if (!auditService.isAuditEnabled(AUDIT_APPLICATION, ("/" + AUDIT_APPLICATION))) {
    throw new WebScriptException(
        "Auditing for " + AUDIT_APPLICATION + " is disabled!");
}
final List<Map<String, Object>> entries =
    new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>(limit);
AuditQueryCallback callback = new AuditQueryCallback() {
    @Override
    public boolean valuesRequired() {
        return true; // true = verbose
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleAuditEntryError(
            Long entryId, String errorMsg, Throwable error) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleAuditEntry(
            Long entryId,
            String applicationName,
            String user,
            long time,
            Map<String, Serializable> values) {
                        // Convert values to Strings
            Map<String, String> valueStrings =
                new HashMap<String, String>(values.size() * 2);
            for (Map.Entry<String, Serializable> mapEntry : values.entrySet()) {
                String key = mapEntry.getKey();
                Serializable value = mapEntry.getValue();
                try {
                    String valueString = DefaultTypeConverter.INSTANCE.convert(
                        String.class, value);
                    valueStrings.put(key, valueString);
                }
                catch (TypeConversionException e) {
                    // Use the toString()
                    valueStrings.put(key, value.toString());
                }

            }
            entry.put(JSON_KEY_ENTRY_VALUES, valueStrings);
        }
        entries.add(entry);
        return true;
    }
};

AuditQueryParameters params = new AuditQueryParameters();
params.setApplicationName(AUDIT_APPLICATION);
params.setForward(true);

auditService.auditQuery(callback, params, maxResults);
```

Though the callback might it look asynchronous, it is not.